# Typical rms values for random jitter in satellite communication

Tags: sampling, jitter, component-values, satellite

I'm trying to find typical values for random jitter in satellite communication and I'm not really finding any values in any documents. Most of the time I only find definitions for different jitter types.

Now I thought that someone here maybe knows resources or the right place to search for such information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which section and sub-section of the circuit of the satellite communication are you talking about?

Comment: As of July 15 2020, you may find a few figures for satellite VoIP communication links here: https://www.whichvoip.com/articles/voip-over-satellite.htm (Figure 3). You can also try and measure jitter for yourself with the help of https://broadbandnow.com/Exede-Internet-speed-test

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention what specific part of the circuitry i meant.
I'm interested in the sampling process in the receiver front end. 
I'm talking about jitter by imperfect sampling.